# Queries across multiple MySQL databases

Tags: mysql, sql, powershell

I have two DBs in my MySQL server, which contain data I want to get from a PowerShell command.

For another project, I have created views in a third DB called `dbView`. In this DB the views are used to compile data from the two other DBs. My views are just some SELECT queries with JOINs.

From my PowerShell point of view, when I connect to a database I can only connect to one DB in the connection string, which means I cannot execute my views.

So my question is: How to make SELECT queries in PowerShell with JOINs to other DBs?

Comment: Please add you view code..

Comment: Schema qualify the table identifier: `<schema name>.<table name>` (Schema and database are the same in MySQL)

Comment: Specify complete table or column name, include database name to it. I.e. not `tablename` but `dbname.tablename` and not `tablename.columnname` but `dbname.tablename.columnname`.

Comment: You're right, I've missed to write my request with table identifier.